# Set group writeable when opening DB with SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE

Tags: c, permissions, sqlite

When I create a new database with `sqlite3_open_v2(path, db3, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL)`, the created database will have `-rw-r--r--` even if the parent folder has `drwxrwsr-x`.

Is there any way I can create the database readable for groups without `chmod` on the database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite creates its database file with `0644` permissions by default.
This can be changed by redefining `SQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS` during compilation.

You also can create an empty file before calling `sqlite3_open*`.